# cycle.js - is there a way to implement event handlers like in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cyclejs

I recently ran into Cycle.js, and, except for what I'm about to ask, I like the framework. Is there a way to implement event handlers directly on the DOM helper? Something like:

```js
function main(sources) {
    //...
    const clickEvent$ = xstream.createSubject() // not a real function, I think
    const counter$ = clickEvent$.fold((counter, amount) => counter + amount, 0)
    const vdom$ = counter$.map(counter => div([
        p(['Counter: ', count]),
        button({
            on: { click: () => clickEvent$.emit(1) }
        },'+'),
        button({
            on: { click: () => clickEvent$.emit(-1) }
        },'-'),
    ]))
    //...
    return sinks
}
```

Or is a feature like React's event handlers being planned?

I know that the example is not (yet) possible, but if something like that gets implemented, component isolation would be a lot easier, and React devs could have minimal issues with using Cycle.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is neither supported nor ever planned to be added. The whole point of the dom driver is to provide a declarative, stream based abstraction, not imperative onclick handlers

Comment: Although programming for decades, I needed to look it up: [Imperative vs Declarative Programming](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/imperative-vs-declarative-programming-difference/).